# Why am I getting error file format not reognized while compiling?

Tags: c, libxml2

I am using libxml2 parser for parsing xml file. But when I compile using using gcc compiler:

```
gcc test.c note.xml -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -o output
```

It gives me following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld:note.xml: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:note.xml:1: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is my test.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>

void readfile(const char* filename) {
    xmlDocPtr doc;
    doc = xmlReadFile(filename,NULL,0);
    if(doc == NULL)
       return;
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
    if(argc != 2)
        return 1;
    LIBXML_TEST_VERSION
    readfile(argv[1]);
    xmlCleanupParser();
    xmlMemoryDump();
    return 0; 
}
```

Here is my xml file:

```
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
      <heading>Reminder</heading>
        <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
   </note>
```

Comment: You can't compile a xml-file. Remove the `note.xml` from your command line.

Comment: You need that .xml file when you *run* your program.  Not when you build it.

Comment: your `readfile()` function can return with out actually reading the XML file. However, in your `main()` function the returned value is not being checked, so these statement: `xmlCleanupParser();
     xmlMemoryDump();` are trying to process a XML file that has not been read.  This is a logic error.  strongly suggest having the error exit and the success exit from `readfile()` return values that the `main()` function can check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error explains it all:

```
/usr/bin/ld:note.xml: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
```

File format not recognized. Which file? `note.xml`. Is it code? No, it isn't part of your C code. It should not be compiled at all, so don't pass it as an argument to `gcc`.